# Change password when reset password on next logon is set in Active directory in linux using Openldap C library

Tags: c, active-directory, openldap

I am trying to reset the password for the active directory user for which "reset password on next logon" is set, using open ldap c code which is similar to the code of ldapmodify. But ldap_bind fails with invalid credentials, with data 773 (password expired error code).

```
ldapmodify -v -x -ZZ -H ldap://<ldap> -D "cn=fi_user,cn=users,dc=qa01,dc=eng,dc=user,dc=com" -w oldpassword -f ~/old_to_new.ldif 
ldap_initialize( ldap://<ldap>/??base )
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773, v2580
```

Is it possible to reset password for this Active directory user ( Reset password on next logon is set) using the ldap protocol in C in linux?

```
    vector<string> Split(string& s, string delim) {
      vector<string> ret;
      auto start = 0U;
      auto end = s.find(delim);
      while (end != std::string::npos) {
        ret.push_back(s.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + delim.length();
        end = s.find(delim, start);
      }
      ret.push_back(s.substr(start));
      return ret;
    }

    void SetLDAPModPassword(LDAPMod* ldap_mod, string& password) {
      std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
      std::u16string utf16_curr_pass = convert.from_bytes("\"" + password + "\"");

      struct berval** ber_arr = new struct berval*[2];
      ber_arr[1] = NULL;
      ber_arr[0] = new struct berval;
      ber_arr[0]->bv_val = new char[utf16_curr_pass.size() * 2];
      memcpy(ber_arr[0]->bv_val,
             utf16_curr_pass.data(),
             utf16_curr_pass.size() * 2);
      ber_arr[0]->bv_len = utf16_curr_pass.size() * 2;
      ldap_mod->mod_vals.modv_bvals = ber_arr;
    }


    string SetLdapOptions(LDAP* ldap_handle) {
      stringstream ss;
      int ret = ldap_set_option(ldap_handle, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, LDAP_OPT_OFF);
      if (ret != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_set_option LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS to LDAP_OPT_OFF failed: "
           << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }

      const int ldap_version = LDAP_VERSION3;
      ret = ldap_set_option(ldap_handle, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &ldap_version);
      if (ret != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_set_option LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION to " << ldap_version
           << " failed: " << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }

      const int cert_flag = LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER;
      ret = ldap_set_option(nullptr, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, &cert_flag);
      if (ret != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_set_option LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT to "
              "LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER failed: "
           << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }

      ret = ldap_start_tls_s(ldap_handle, NULL, NULL );
      if (ret != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_start_tls_s failed: " << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }

      int timelimit = 15;
      struct timeval timeout = {.tv_sec = timelimit, .tv_usec = 0};

      ret = ldap_set_option(ldap_handle, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, &timeout);
      if (ret != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_set_option LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT to "
              "LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER failed: "
           << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }

      ret = ldap_set_option(ldap_handle, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, &timelimit);
      if (ret != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_set_option LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT to " << timelimit
           << " failed: " << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }

      ret = ldap_set_option(ldap_handle, LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT, &timeout);
      if (ret != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_set_option LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT to "
           << timeout.tv_sec << " failed: " << ldap_err2string(ret);
      }

      return ss.str();
    }

    string ChangeActiveDirectoryPassword(string domain_controller,
                                         string domain,
                                         string username,
                                         string curr_password,
                                         string new_password) {
      int ret;
      LDAP* ldap_handle = nullptr;

      char passwd_attr[16] = "unicodePwd";
      std::stringstream ss;

      ss << "ldap://" << domain_controller << ":389";

      LOG(INFO) << ss.str();

      ret = ldap_initialize(&ldap_handle, ss.str().c_str());
      ss.str(std::string());
      if (ret != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_initialize failed: " << ldap_err2string(ret);
        return ss.str();
      }


      string ret_err = SetLdapOptions(ldap_handle);
      if (!ret_err.empty()) {
        return ret_err;
      }

      stringstream domain_stream;
      domain_stream << "CN=" << FLAGS_username << ",CN=Users,";

      vector<string> split_string_vec = Split(domain, ".");
      int ii = 0;
      for (auto subdomain : split_string_vec) {
        if (ii != 0) {
          domain_stream << ",";
        }
        domain_stream << string("DC=") << subdomain;
        ii++;
      }

      string domain_string = domain_stream.str();

      struct berval passwd_berval;
      passwd_berval.bv_len = curr_password.size();
      passwd_berval.bv_val = new char[curr_password.size() + 1];
      strcpy(passwd_berval.bv_val, curr_password.c_str());

      LOG(INFO) << domain_string;
      struct berval* servercredp;
      ret = ldap_sasl_bind_s(ldap_handle,
                             domain_string.c_str(),
                             LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE,
                             &passwd_berval,
                             NULL,
                             NULL,
                             &servercredp);
      delete[] passwd_berval.bv_val;

      if (ret != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
        ss << "ldap_sasl_bind_s failed: " << ldap_err2string(ret);
        //return ss.str();
      }

LDAPMod delete_old_pass;
  memset(&delete_old_pass, 0, sizeof(LDAPMod));
  char unicode_str[16] = "unicodePwd";;
  delete_old_pass.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_DELETE | LDAP_MOD_BVALUES;
  delete_old_pass.mod_type = unicode_str;

  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
  std::u16string utf16_curr_pass =
      convert.from_bytes("\"" + FLAGS_curr_passwd + "\"");
  struct berval** del_ber_arr = new struct berval*[2];
  del_ber_arr[1] = NULL;
  del_ber_arr[0] = new struct berval;
  del_ber_arr[0]->bv_val = new char[utf16_curr_pass.size() * 2];
  memcpy(del_ber_arr[0]->bv_val,
         utf16_curr_pass.data(),
         utf16_curr_pass.size() * 2);
  del_ber_arr[0]->bv_len = utf16_curr_pass.size() * 2;
  delete_old_pass.mod_vals.modv_bvals = del_ber_arr;

  LDAPMod add_new_pass;
  LDAPMod *add_new_pass_pointer = &add_new_pass;
  memset(&add_new_pass, 0, sizeof(LDAPMod));
  add_new_pass.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_ADD | LDAP_MOD_BVALUES;
  add_new_pass.mod_type = unicode_str;

  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert1;
  std::u16string utf16_new_pass =
      convert1.from_bytes("\"" + FLAGS_new_passwd + "\"");
  struct berval** add_ber_arr = new struct berval*[2];
  add_ber_arr[1] = NULL;
  add_ber_arr[0] = new struct berval;
  add_ber_arr[0]->bv_val = new char[utf16_new_pass.size() * 2];
  memcpy(add_ber_arr[0]->bv_val,
         utf16_new_pass.data(),
         utf16_new_pass.size() * 2);
  add_ber_arr[0]->bv_len = utf16_new_pass.size() * 2;
  add_new_pass.mod_vals.modv_bvals = add_ber_arr;

  LDAPMod *mods[3];
  mods[0] = &delete_old_pass;
  mods[1] = &add_new_pass;
  mods[2] = NULL;

  ret = ldap_modify_ext_s(
                ldap_handle,
                domain.c_str(),
                mods,
                NULL,
                NULL);

  CHECK_EQ(ret, LDAP_SUCCESS)
      << "ldap_modify_ext_s() failed." << ldap_err2string(ret) << " dn "
      << domain << " pass " << curr_passwd.bv_val;

  ldap_destroy(ldap_handle);
  LOG(INFO) << "LDAP password changed.";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like C code to me.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Drop the C tag or post some C code.  [Edit] your post and ask a more useful question.

Comment: @jwdonahue added the c++ code that uses openldap c library. The ldap_sasl_bind_s is failing with invalid credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Note that "changing" a password and "resetting" a password are considered two different things.

- Changing a password is when the user provides the old password and the new password
- Resetting a password is when a user provides a new password without knowing the old password. The user must have the "Reset password" permission on the target account.

The procedure for both is described in the documentation for the [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) attribute.

I don't know the OpenLDAP C library, so I can't give you code, but I can describe the process.

**Reset a password**

First you must bind using a user account that has the "Reset password" on the target account. Then:

> If the Modify request contains a single replace operation containing a value Vrep for unicodePwd, the server considers the request to be an administrative reset of the password, that is, a password modification without knowledge of the old password. The server decodes Vrep using the password decoding procedure documented later in this section and uses it as the new password.

So you need to send an LDAP replace operation for the `unicodePwd` attribute with the new password in the required format. The required format is:

> the DC requires that the password value be specified in a UTF-16 encoded Unicode string containing the password surrounded by quotation marks, which has been BER-encoded as an octet string per the Object(Replica-Link) syntax.

**Changing a password**

First you have to bind using *any* account that can authenticate to the domain. The account you use doesn't need any special permissions. It just needs to be able to authenticate.

Then you can change the password. The documentation says:

> If the Modify request contains a delete operation containing a value Vdel for unicodePwd followed by an add operation containing a value Vadd for unicodePwd, the server considers the request to be a request to change the password. The server decodes Vadd and Vdel using the password decoding procedure documented later in this section. Vdel is the old password, while Vadd is the new password.

To clarify, you need to send an LDAP request to modify the `unicodePwd` attribute that contains two operations in the same request:

1. A delete operation that contains the value of the old password. Knowing the old password is what gives you permission to change the password.
2. An add operation that contains the value of the new password.

The format of the password strings is the same as when resetting a password.

Comment: So if we need domain administrator credentials to reset the password, How does the windows clients resets password on user with reset password on next logon field set without domain administrator credentials? I dont think they use domain admin creds to reset the password.

Comment: You're still confusing "reset" with "change". They are two different things. When an account has the "User must **change** password on next logon" flag, then user is forced to change their password on next logon by providing their old password and then their new one. Knowing the old password is the authorization needed to change the password. No administrator credentials are used or needed.

Comment: Even when truly "resetting" a password (setting a new password without knowing the old password), you don't necessarily need a domain admin account. You just need any account that has the "Reset password" permission on the account. A domain admin will certainly have that, but any account can be given that permission.

Comment: Thanks @gabriel .. You mentioned "When an account has the "User must change password on next logon" flag, then user is forced to change their password on next logon by providing their old password and then their new one. Knowing the old password is the authorization needed to change the password. No administrator credentials are used or needed". How do I this programmatically or cmd line tools in linux? I tried to bind using the user account with old password but bind using the old password is failing with invalid credentials with special code (773) password expired

Comment: Read over the "Changing a password" section of my answer again. Everything you need is there. You can't bind with an account with an expired password. You have to bind with a working account. *Any* account will do - it does not need any special permissions. Create an account just for your application to use if you want.

Comment: Your code right now is doing a single "modify" request, which is a "reset", not a "change". If you want to "change" the password, you need to send a "delete" and an "add" in the same request. I explained that in more detail in my answer.